# Is there a way to automate webpage login and download report?

Tags: power-automate, office365connectors

Is there a way to automate a task a webpage login and download report maybe with power-automate or some other method?

1. open web page
2. enter any parameters.
3. click download button.
4. save download to local drive.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to automate it using Power Automate Desktop, you can take control of the browser, If the webpage structure remains the same and the login doesn't ask additional captcha except usual login and password fields.

You can configure the automation by

1. First opening the webpage using Browser Control in PAD(Power Automate Desktop)
2. Entering the username password can be automatically done with PAD (both should
   be defined in the
   automation)
3. Capture the web element using the action to click a button - either to
   navigate the page or download something.
4. Can save the file into local system using PAD by usual browser download or mentioning separate path in the automation.

Answer (score 1):

If you know how to code such as Python. Then Selenium,playwright,Clicknium would be a good choice. Clicknium should be the most simple one, but it can only run in Windows. In include a Recorder to identity the UI element and include APIs for click and set_text.
If you don't want to code, you can use RPA tools, such as power automate and UI path.